# Memory Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, browser

So i have an Angular web-app. It first get data with http request, then I do some tests on it and then display it according to results.
Once it's done, i regularly check if there's no data's update. If there is, I get and test it and display it. 
But after many hours of use, browser (firefox and chrome) crashes and say that there is a memory leak.
Have you any idea where it might come ? If you don't know, can u give me advice for how to find the entry  point of  leaks.

Thank you.

Comment: This might help you http://makandracards.com/makandra/31289-how-to-create-giant-memory-leaks-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code is hard to tell you exactly what to do, but try emptying your variables at every loop.

```
var myData = null;
or
delete myData.property;
```

Comment: `delete` removes a property from an object. It has no effect on variables.

Comment: It should if the data is stored in a property. As i wrote before without knowing how the code structured it is difficult to tell the right method of releasing memory. It was a blind suggestion.